# Change the default Magento 2 toplinks

Tags: magento-2.1, toplinks

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

My top links (above the logo) are:

1. Compare Products
2. Default welcome msg!
3. My Account
4. My Wish List
5. Create an Account
6. Sign In

I need to know how, **from my custom theme** (I want to stay safe from the overwrites that occur when updating Magento), I could have only:

1. My Cart
2. My Wish List
3. Sign In

In `app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`I have changed:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

into:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <referenceBlock  name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock  name="compare-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock  name="wishlist_link" remove="true"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

With **no effect**.

How can I achieve this goal? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to add your custom toplinks in your custom theme so when you upgrade magento version, it doesn't lose your changes?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: I just tried my code, it is working for me, the only thing is that i got the name for the wishlist-link wrong. Did you try to clear the cache via `php bin/magento cache:clean` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom layout file to your theme.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
    <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
    </body>
</page>
```

There you can reference the elements you want to remove and do so with the attribute `remove="true"`.

Comment: I do have a `default.xml` file.

Comment: With what content? Did you already try to remove the links via your layout file?

Comment: With `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
        </arguments>
</block>` See question. I have edited it

Comment: Try to just add what you want deleted after your block declaration, inside your default.xml (see my edited answer).

Comment: The code `<referenceBlock  name="compare-products-link" remove="true"/>` does not work.  The "Compare Products" is still there.