# How can I add classes to the main product-page blocks in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a (custom) **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the **product page**, I need to add Bootstrap classes to the code below

```
<!-- Product photo Begin -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="product-info">
        <div class="product media">
            <!-- More code here -->
        </div>

        <div class="product-info-main">
            <!-- More code here -->
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Product photo End -->
```

like this

```
<!-- Product Info Begin -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="product-info">
        <div class="product media col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <!-- More code here -->
        </div>

        <div class="product-info-main col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <!-- More code here -->
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

so that it aligns nicely.

My `catalog_product_view.xml`file contains this code:

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" before="product.info.media"/>
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" before="product.info.details"/>
    <move element="product.info.details" destination="main"/>
    <referenceContainer name="catalog.product.related" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="product-info">
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Questions:**

1. In what files can I find the code for the "Product photo" and "Product info" blocks?
2. If it is the case, where, in my custom theme shell I copy them to overwrite the defaults safely (irreversibly)?

Comment: It is not a duplicate: I can't find the `.phtml` files corresponding to the blocks I want to add classes to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make it via layout xml:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="content.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row" before="-">
                <container name="content.row.product-info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlClass="product-info-main col-xs-12 col-sm-8" />
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlClass="product media col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="content.row.product-info" before="-" />
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="content.row.product-info" />

        <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="catalog.product.related" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Write me if you have any issues.

Comment: Please, see the edit. Your code is good, but I need to hide my sidebar and _it_ is showing the sidebar.

Comment: Try again, I removed `div.sidebar.main` and `catalog.product.related` in my layout.

Comment: The `<nav class="navigation navbar navbar-default" data-action="navigation">//more code</div>` has to disapear from `<div class="column main"> <nav class="navigation navbar navbar-default" data-action="navigation"></div><div class="row"><div class="product-info"></div></div></div>`

Comment: I have moved the top bar to the left side and stacked it. So, the product categories form a vertical, left side navigation.

Comment: Great, so layout is good now? Сan I help you with anything else?

Comment: It is not ok: removing the sidebar does not help. How can I sen you my default.xml?

Comment: You can to send code via https://pastebin.com service. Why removing the sidebar doesn't help?

Comment: See it [HERE](https://pastebin.com/zZuStV4a).

Comment: Ok, what is wrong now?

Comment: I have added, above `<referenceContainer name="catalog.product.related" remove="true" />` the folowing: ` <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlClass="product-info-main col-xs-12 col-sm-8" />
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlClass="product media col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />`. It is ok.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to hear it. Is question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202318/change-the-default-magento-2-toplinks actually for you? If yes - I'll form my answer.

Comment: It is my  question, but it regards another issue.